# wp_enqueue_scripts not firing in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

Really basic, I'm afraid. My scripts aren't loading when I put them as part of a function triggered by the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action in `functions.php`. If I put them outside of that action as part of the main file, they load fine, but of course this is bad form. So:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'intranet-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

works but throws up errors in debugging but

```
function intranet_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'intranet-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'intranet_scripts' );
```

does nothing, it doesn't even throw up any errors. I must be missing something super basic but I can't for the life of me see what it is. I've had a look at similar questions here, and they all seem to revolve around trying to use `wp_enqueue_script` to load a style, which I'm not doing. Help?

Comment: That's the proper way to proceed to include stylesheets, problem must be somewhere else. If you provide a valid path to `wp_enqueue_style` (not the theme stylesheet uri), does it works? edit: just in case, you don't need to include the theme stylesheet manually, it's already included.

Comment: HI Vard, no, it doesn't do anything even with the URL. The function's not firing at all (e.g. if I put an echo statement in there, nothing happens). Also, the style.css is *not* being automatically included if I don't enqueue it, so is that indicative of a bigger problem?

Comment: Does your `header.php` have `wp_head()` function?

Comment: Whey you say "my scripts aren't loading", do you mean "my *styles* aren't loading"?

Comment: @RahilWazir - It did not. I am an idiot. Working now, if you want to add that as an answer.

Comment: @MattGibson - It didn't work if I had scripts in there also; I just picked a bad example. Nothing inside that function was firing, because of the missing wp_head().

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin Just checked, I was wrong about the fact it is automatically included - as the root `style.css` is the theme definition file I thought it was included with it, which is not the case.

Comment: Yeah, just found that too. You'd think Wordpress would automatically hook the main style.css in. Your solution still worked though, so thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was missing `wp_head()` from the template, so the action wasn't firing, hence the function wasn't triggered.